# CAN bus interface does not come up after CAN bus restart

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I am fighting with an industrial PC running Ubuntu 18.04.1

This PC is equipped with Apacer CAN module APEHC-D40 to receive data from external sensors. 95% of the time the module is running fine and CAN bus data is successfully received but in 5% of cases it is getting stalled. As the PC is located remotely it is a bit difficult to figure out the exact set of circumstances leading to "no data" situation but I believe it is somewhat related to a situation when the PC is running connected to the CAN bus, then due to other requirements the CAN network is powered down, the PC is still on while the CAN network is down and then when CAN network is up sometimes Apacer CAN module does not detect it as being up and requires restart. CAN module is managed as a virtual network interface by Network Manager. Interestingly enough, if I check interface state it is shown as UNKNOWN all the time (not sure if it is a problem but I would expect UP).

```
rig@drillhub:~$ sudo ip -det link show can0
8: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
    link/can  promiscuity 0 numtxqueues 1 numrxqueues 1 gso_max_size 65536 gso_max_segs 65535
```

This is the only bit in syslog that does not look right to me though I am not sure if it is related.

```
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub slcand[824]: starting on TTY device /dev/ttyCAN0
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub slcand[825]: attached TTY /dev/ttyCAN0 to netdevice apacer_can0
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub kernel: [    6.968400] tty_warn_deprecated_flags: 'slcand' is using deprecated serial flags (with no effect): 00008200
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub kernel: [    6.969104] can0: renamed from apacer_can0
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub slcand[825]: netdevice apacer_can0 renamed to can0
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd-networkd[498]: apacer_can0: Interface name change detected, apacer_can0 has been renamed to can0.
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd-udevd[826]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub NetworkManager[647]: <info>  [1622614602.1822] manager: (can0): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd-udevd[826]: link_config: could not get ethtool features for apacer_can0
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd-udevd[826]: Could not set offload features of apacer_can0: No such device
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub NetworkManager[647]: <info>  [1622614602.1950] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/apacer_can0, iface: apacer_can0)
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub NetworkManager[647]: <info>  [1622614602.1950] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/apacer_can0, iface: apacer_can0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub networkd-dispatcher[616]: WARNING:Unknown index 8 seen, reloading interface list
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd-networkd[498]: can0: Link UP
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd-networkd[498]: can0: Gained carrier
Jun  2 06:16:42 drillhub systemd[1]: Started Setup CAN buses using the Apacer CAN module..
```

Does anyone know what I can check in order to find out what's wrong with this CAN module setup?

Cheers